# GameTime is always 0 - MonoGame (XNA) - C#

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-4.0

Currently, my sprites loop at the same speed that MonoGame loops through it's code. I want to slow this process down by creating a delay using GameTime. It never worked, however, so I decided that I would use debug.WriteLine() to check if GameTime updated. It didn't, ever.

```
abstract class Entity
{
    protected GameTime _gameTime;
    public TimeSpan timer { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
        _gameTime = new GameTime();
        timer = _gameTime.TotalGameTime;
    }

    public void UpdateTimer()
    {
        timer += _gameTime.TotalGameTime;
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer: " + timer.Milliseconds);
    }
}
```

UpdateTimer() runs continously in the game loop, but always writes "0" in the debug output.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: General note: You should (almost) always use the `Total_` properties (`TotalSeconds`, `TotalMilliseconds`, ...) when dealing with `GameTime`.  The "non-Total" methods return only that *part* of the time, while the "Total" ones return the entire span expressed as the time unit you want.  For example, if 1.7 seconds pass, `Milliseconds` will return `700`, while `TotalMilliseconds` will return `1700`.  `Seconds` will return `1`, and `TotalSeconds` will return `1.7`. Generally, the only time to use the "plain" properties is when you want to do special formatting, or something else non-standard.

Comment: Also note, you don't actually need to keep your own accumulated timer, `GameTime` already does that for you, in the [`GameTime.TotalGameTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.totalgametime.aspx) property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `_gameTime` is `0` because it is just initalized, thats it.

Your Game class (which inherits from `Game`) got an Update method, with the parameter type `GameTime`. This parameter is your current frametime. So your `UpdateTimer` should have also an `GameTime` parameter and should be called in your `Game.Update`

```
public void UpdateTimer(GameTime gameTime)
{
    timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
    Debug.WriteLine("Timer: " + timer.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Milliseconds`!  Use `TotalMilliseconds`.  `Milliseconds` waps every 1000 ms (if `1500` ms pass between updates, it will only return `500`). `TotalMilliseconds` will give you the time since last update expressed completely in milliseconds.

Comment: Just copied it from him, so yeah.. I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the main gameTime to the Entity. ex-(Entity._gameTime = gametime) Then it will start updating.